# Saving after moving values from left to right using list boxes

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me for the list boxes. 
What I am trying to do is:
I selected two items from list box and moved them to right.

[image]

I saved Excel file. I reopened the file and nothing was present in the right.

[image]

Please help. I have used following code in VBA:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
    Next iCtr
    Me.ListBox2.Clear
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub BTN_moveAllRight_Click()  
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
    Next iCtr
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedLeft_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedRight_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
     Unload Me
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim rngItems As Range
    Set rngItems = Sheets("Subject Disposition").Range("Route")

    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    Me.ListBox2.Clear

    With Me.ListBox1
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .ListFillRange = ""
        For Each myCell In rngItems.Cells
            If Trim(myCell) <> "" Then
                .AddItem myCell.Value
            End If
        Next myCell
    End With

    Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
    Me.ListBox2.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
End Sub
```

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please consider **revising** your question to include more detail, including screenshots (if you don't have enough rep to upload them here, post them to imgur.com and add the links).  Include more detail description, rather than simply dumping your code. The current code doesn't seem to have anything resembling "moving left or right" so it's not clear what you expect should happen...

Comment: Also note that changes to a form's controls generally do not persist beyond the form's `_Terminate` event.  If you need to modify the "default", you will have to do something in the form's `Initialize` or `Activate` event handler...

Comment: @DavidZemens Many thanks for your comments. What I am trying to do is that I have moved two values from left box to right as shown in screenshot_1 (http://i.imgur.com/YwhuXyw.jpg). After saving the excel file, If I reopen the excel file,it again comes to default settings as shown in screenshot_2 (http://imgur.com/9vCJfEb). The changes have not been saved.

Comment: What you want can't be done using the code you're using. As what David said, the changes will not persist beyond code termination. What you can do is pass the items you selected somewhere in the worksheet then use *RowSource* property to fetch it later. Or better yet, update your code to using that property altogether.

Comment: @L42 Many thanks for your comments and help. Could you please guide me as what and where to add the property. I am not expert in VBA. By reading different blogs and help, I have written code mentioned above. Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Change the properties manually in the form's "Properties" window in the VBE: http://imgur.com/PjGdUru but of course this will not work with lists. As I mentioned earlier, it will be necessary to populate "default" or initial values in the form's `Initialize` or `Activate` event handlers.

Comment: Sure, I made a sample demo for you. See my post.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample for you.
First set up the Source Sheet (in this sample, we use Sheet1) and the UserForm like what you see below:

[image]

As you can see, we have the initial data or list in Cell A1:A10 in Sheet1.
To display it in the *UserForm* you created, you use *RowSource* property as seen in *UserForm_Initialize* event as what David pointed out. (See below) 
And then you see the codes for the rest of the buttons which moves items selected from left to right and vise versa.
Also the move all to left or right button.
Basically, what we're doing is manipulating *Range Objects* in *Sheet1* and then updates the *RowSource* property at the end of each code block to make it look like we are manipulating the Listboxes.
Now when you save the worksheet, It will retain whatever value Ranges A1:A10 and B1:B10 have. HTH

```
Option Explicit
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'move item right to left
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With Me.ListBox2 'right listbox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) = True Then
                Set rng = Sheet1.Range("B1:B10").Find(.List(i), [B10])
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    With Sheet1
                        If Len(.Range("A1").Value) = 0 Then
                            j = 1
                        Else
                            j = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                        End If
                        rng.Copy .Range("A" & j)
                        rng.Delete xlUp
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    DoEvents
    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "A1:A10"
    Me.ListBox2.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "B1:B10"
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'move item left to right
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With Me.ListBox1 'left listbox
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) = True Then
                Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Find(.List(i), [A10])
                If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                    With Sheet1
                        If Len(.Range("B1").Value) = 0 Then
                            j = 1
                        Else
                            j = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                        End If
                        rng.Copy .Range("B" & j)
                        rng.Delete xlUp
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    DoEvents
    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "A1:A10"
    Me.ListBox2.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "B1:B10"
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() 'move all to left
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheet1
        If Me.ListBox2.ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set rng = .Range("B1", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Len(.Range("A1").Value) = 0 Then
            rng.Copy .Range("A1")
        Else
            rng.Copy .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        rng.ClearContents
    End With

    DoEvents
    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "A1:A10"
    Me.ListBox2.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "B1:B10"
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click() 'move all to right
    Dim rng As Range

    With Sheet1
        If Me.ListBox1.ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Set rng = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If Len(.Range("B1").Value) = 0 Then
            rng.Copy .Range("B1")
        Else
            rng.Copy .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        rng.ClearContents
    End With

    DoEvents
    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "A1:A10"
    Me.ListBox2.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "B1:B10"
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Initialize the left and right listbox value
    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "A1:A10"
    Me.ListBox2.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "B1:B10"
End Sub
```